# Get the top level OU from a AD user via Powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am asking this question mainly to ask if there is a better way to do what I have working. I would also like to know if anyone sees any issues with getting this information this way.

I am trying to get the top level OU that a user is in, and any lower level OUs. The main problem is that we have multiple sites, some of which have multiple layers of OUs for user accounts (`ou=doctors,ou=Users,ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com`), and some sites that just have a single OU (`ou=Users,ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com`). I used the script below to get the DN path, split it, and rebuild it backwards with the last three pieces. Can anyone see any issues with doing it this way. Something about it just feels wrong....

```
$user = Get-ADUser CKnutson
$user.DistinguishedName
# Returns: CN=Cory Knutson,OU=IT,OU=Users,OU=Site,DC=example,DC=com

$split = $user.DistinguishedName.Split(',')
$path = "$($split[-3]),$($split[-2]),$($split[-1])"

Write-Host $path
# Returns: OU=Site,DC=example,DC=com
```

Just to state, the end goal was for me to get the path to the "Disabled" OU that we have just inside of each of the "Site" OUs. So my scripting could move the object when disabling the account to the proper place, in that site's top level OU (`OU=Disabled,OU=Site,DC=example,DC=com`).

Comment: Don't think I'd necessarily call anything wrong, but is the final goal to have it in the DN format? If not you could also call the canonical name and split that. I think those two attributes are both going to require some splitting and/or joining but are probably the only way to achieve the stated goal with any kind of ease.

Comment: The other thought that occurs is simply pattern matching your domain name with regex or with a straight up string match and splitting off only the stuff after -- ahem before -- that to put in another cell in your CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone see any issues with doing it this way.

Yes, I see two immediate problems that might arise from your current approach.

---

### 1. Escaped commas

Consider an OU with a comma in its name, like: `OU=Users\, Admin,DC=corp,DC=example`

Your use of `string.Split()` won't care about the escape sequence and you end up with:

```
 Admin,DC=corp,DC=example
```

Use the `-split` regex operator with a lookbehind to make sure you ignore escaped commas:

```
$parts = $user.DistinguishedName -split '(?<!\\),'
```

---

### 2. Portability

Your code assumes that the NC part of the DN (eg. `DC=example,DC=com`), will always be just 2 labels wide. This means your code will fail if you use it in scripts you might want to reuse in other domains/environments.

I would grab each part, from right-to-left until I find one *without* the `DC` RDN prefix:

```
$topParts = foreach($part in $parts[-1..-$parts.Length]){
    $part
    if($part -notlike 'DC=*'){
        break
    }
}
# Remember to reverse the RDNs again
$path = $topParts[-1..-$topParts.Length] -join ','
```

Comment: But if I want the top level OU included, the if statement would be `if($part -notlike 'DC=*'){$part;break}`, correct? Then it would include the first non-DN piece, which would be the top level folder/OU.

Comment: Look at the line just before `if($part -notlike ...` - when we `break` we've already emitted `$part` :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is simpler to use Pathname COM object and simply ask for the parent of the DN. You can put this in a `while` loop to get the hierarchy of the object. Example using my [ADName](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ADName/) module:

```
$dn = Get-ADUser user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$parent = $dn | Get-ADName -Format Parent
while ( $parent -like "OU=*" ) {
  $parent
  $parent = $parent | Get-ADName -Format Parent
}
```

Example output:

```
OU=Level 3,OU=Level 2,OU=Level 1,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
OU=Level 2,OU=Level 1,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
OU=Level 1,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're after the DN of the path to the account? You can do that with a regular expression that uses the (?) ungreedy qualifier. There is no split, so escaped commas are not an issue.

```
"CN=Cory Knutson,ou=doctors,ou=Users,ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com" -match ".+?,(OU=.+)"
$matches[1]
ou=doctors,ou=Users,ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com

"CN=Knutson\, Cory,ou=doctors,ou=Users,ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com" -match ".+?,(OU=.+)"
$matches[1]
ou=doctors,ou=Users,ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com

"CN=Cory Knutson,ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com" -match ".+?,(OU=.+)"
$matches[1]
ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com
```

**Edit**
I was unclear from the phrase `the top level OU that a user is in, and any lower level OUs.` You can also do this:

```
$dn = "CN=Cory Knutson,ou=doctors,ou=Users,ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com"
$last = ($dn.toUpper()).lastIndexOf("OU=")
$dn.substring($last)
ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: I wanted only the top level OU, so all three should return: `ou=Site,dc=example,dc=com`